# Android studio内にあるview all attributesを見つけたい

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

一番下にある、view all attributesが見つからないです。二枚目の写真は見本なんですけど、
一枚目の写真は自分が開発している画像になります
view all attributesを見つけたいのですが、view all attributesが見つけられなくて時間が経過していく一方です
言語はKotlinです
言葉足らずで申し訳あります
どなたかご教授いただけると幸いです

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 一枚目の画像の一番下に "All Attributes" という折り畳みされた項目があるように見えますが、こちらは違いますか？

Answer (score 0):

AndroidStudioのバージョンが違うのではないですか？
自分の手元にある4.0では上のタイプでしたが、3.2のスクリーンショットを探したら下のタイプでした。
([ここ](https://developers-jp.googleblog.com/2018/06/android-studio-3-2-canary.html)から参照)
[image: AndroidStudio3.2のスクリーンショット]

何かの本を参考にしているのであれば、その本で使用しているAndroidStudioのバージョンに合わせてはいかがですか。
以下から過去のバージョンのAndroidStudioが入手できます。

- [Android Studioのダウンロードアーカイブ](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive?hl=ja)